# Unit test output with more than 1 “TRUE”

Tags: r, unit-testing

When I run my unit tests (with runTests() ), I want two "TRUE"s to be the output, not just one "TRUE". How do I make this happen with what I have here (not all my code is here for concision)?

```
runTests <- function()
{
  test_oneWordCounty()
  test_twoWordCounty()
} # runTests

#TEST1
test_oneWordCounty <- function() {
#extra code... here
return(
  checkEquals(stateAbbr, "CA") #check the state abbreviation is correct
) }
  #TEST2
test_twoWordCounty <- function() {
#extra code... here
return(
  checkEquals(stateZip, "California"), #check the state identification is correct
)) }
```

Comment: Did you try `return(list(test_oneWordCounty(), test_twoWordCounty()))` in `runTests` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can only ever return one object. However, this is pretty easy to work around, as it just means you need to combine everything you want to return into a single object. For example:

```
runTests <- function()
{
  c(test_oneWordCounty(), 
    test_twoWordCounty()
  )
} # runTests
```